# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, tiff

I want to install tifffile package from  terminal:

```
pip install tifffile
```

I am getting the following error

```
  gcc -pthread -shared -L/home/l-01-314/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/l-01-314/anaconda3/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/tifffile/_tifffile.o -L/home/l-01-314/anaconda3/lib -lpython3.5m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/tifffile/_tifffile.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

any idea why I am getting this error ?

Comment: what's the solution if we don't want to use conda?

Comment: sorry for being late, I am not sure but you should install the gcc which is compatible with your interpreter in my case the interpreter is "Anaconda". If you are using "Python" interpreter you should use "pip".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, there was a wrong link from system gcc so I installed gcc for python anaconda via conda.

```
conda install -c anaconda gcc=4.8.5
```